# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Tags: python, pandas

Bom dia! Estou iniciando meus estudo em python-pandas, e estou com um problema que parece de simples resolução. Mas não para mim. Ainda. 
Estou seguindo esse tutorial: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html

Consigo criar o dataframe, porém ao tentar o comando "df.loc[df.AAA >= 5,'BBB'] = -1", tenho um erro. A mensagem de erro é grande, mas o final é esse: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'". Alguém saberia me dizer o que fazer para resolver esse problema? Obrigado

Comment: Coloque o código na pergunta e a mensagem de erro. Faça isso entrando em [edit]; aproveite e faça o [tour] pela comunidade para aprender mais sobre o site.

Comment: Ou você colocou algumoutro valor intermediário na variável `df`, ou tem algo errado com sua instalação. Qual é o retorno se voce colocar só "df" e enter após esse erro? Deveria ser o dataframe com os valores originais.

Se você reiniciar o exemplo, ver a saída do dataframe, e ainda assim tiver o mesmo erro, tente desinstalar o pandas, o notebook e o Python e instalar tudo de volta. (essa não é uma solução comum ou recomendada para problemas em Python, mas essa mensagem de erro sugere um problema interno das bibliotecas, e é logo na primeira atribuição para transformar o df)

Comment: Vou reinstalar tudo. O erro aparece ao tentar usar o .loc. Ao digitar df o dataframe aparece normalmente. Não acrescentei nada. Apenas segui o exemplo do tutorial. Obrigado.